# Gtx 1050 in vulkan: Xlib: extension "NV-GLX" missing on display ":0"

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, cuda, vulkan

I was messing up, trying to do some dev with Vulkan.

At the time of building the examples and samples, but in execution time, the library uses the integrated graphics (Intel UHD 620) instead of the dedicated graphics card(Nvidia GTX 1050).

After a few lines of code, a small program that tells the name of the physical devices gives this information:

```
Xlib:  extension "NV-GLX" missing on display ":0".
Intel(R) UHD Graphics 620 (Kabylake GT2)
```

Another program, this time in OpenGL says as follows:

```
Renderer: Mesa DRI Intel(R) UHD Graphics 620 (Kabylake GT2)
```

And something similar about Cuda lacking a cuda-capable device.

I have tried swapping drivers, the current version is Nvidia 396 open source, but the error keeps showing up. The screen is alright, and I haven't tried out any games.

How do I fix this?

Comment: Have you tried to select the video using `prime-select`?  To change to the NVIDIA the command would be `sudo prime-select nvidia` then you will probably have to reboot the system for the settings to take effect.

Answer (score 0):

Install these:

```
sudo apt install nvidia-cuda-toolkit 
sudo apt install libvulkan1 libvulkan1:i386
```

Comment: Sorry to say that, but didn't work.